# Ubuntu 13.10, virtualbox 4.2.16r86992, vm with bridge or host only network does not start

Tags: networking, virtualbox, 13.10

I set up bridge or host only netwrok in my VM. And when I start it I got error:
    Failed to open a session for the virtual machine debian.

```
VD: error VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file '/home/valery/Debian 6 64-bit/Debian 6 64-bit.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: I am having the same issue, could be a bug!

Answer (score 4):

I have recently reported this problem as a bug to Launchpad .

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1220724

The bug has now been Confirmed.

Comment: It seems like the bug has already been fixed in the official vagrant package. After running `apt-get upgrade virtualbox` it  works again.